# Consistency of amorphous sets with $ZF + AC_\omega$

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let's call $ZF$ the Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, $AC$ the full axiom of choice, $DC$ the axiom of dependent choice and $AC_\omega$ the axiom of countable choice.

We know that $ZF$+"existence of amorphous sets" is consistent.
We also know that $ZF$+$DC$+"existence of amorphous sets" is not consistent (and so $ZF$+$AC$+"existence of amorphous sets" is not consistent).

My question is the following: is $ZF$+$AC_\omega$+"existence of amorphous sets" consistent?

Comment: Since countable choice implies every infinite set is Dedekind infinite, no, it's not consistent.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you! How can I prove that $AC_\omega$ implies every infinite set is Dedekind infinite?

Comment: @effezeta If $X$ is an infinite set, use $AC_\omega$ to choose, for each $n\in\omega$, an $n$-tuple of distinct elements of $X$. Concatenate those $n$-tuples (in order of increasing $n$) to make an $\omega$-sequence of (not necessarily distinct) elements of $X$. Delete repetitions from this sequence and you have an $\omega$-sequence of distinct elements of $X$. So $X$ is Dedekind-infinite.